# Core Data persistence after uninstall a application

Tags: ios, swift, core-data, persistence, uninstallation

Before I delete an application, I want to be asked for:

> Do you want to delete also the application data?

as we know it from other applications. I searched for it but I don't found any clue. It is related to CoreData.

Do you know how I can achieve this?

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When your application is deleted, its associated data will be as well.

You can instead offer to persist it to an external resource (Firebase, Azure, etc.). Then, it can be available at a later date. However, you must do this prior to deletion, as there is no way for your app to know it is being deleted & respond to it.

Comment: But if I want to delete a game for example on my iPhone I will be asked: "Do you want to delete also the application data?". Or is it only for games?

Comment: When a user deletes an app, everything associated with it is deleted. It is not possible to leave anything behind.